# Error loading page after redirect to an MVC3 action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post-redirect-get, redirecttoaction

Scenario: I have a view (let's call it `Index.cshtml`) that posts a form to a controller action (let's call it `GetWorkList`).

`GetWorkList` runs and then returns a partial view `WorkReport`. After that the user can modify and save some data through `ModifyDuration` action, which in turn should returns `GetWorkList`(the same that I mentioned above). Then the partial view is updated as it should, but I get an error message: `Error loading page` that dissappear before the the page is loaded completely.

What should I do to not have this error message?

**Controller code:**

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetWorkList(string date)
    {
     .....instructions
       return PartialView("WorkReport", model);
    }

      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ModifyDuration(string newDuration, string id, string date)
    {
       .....instructions
      return RedirectToAction("GetWorkList", new
        {
            date = date
        });
    }
```

**Error indicated by the browser:**

[image: mozilla error]

Comment: Shouldn't `GetWorkList` have `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]` since you are posting to this controller action?

Comment: I used `[HttpPost]` and is it' not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be specific without seeing your views, but it would appear that the error is because you are invoking the partial view from within a view that was rendered as part of a POST request (the get requests succeed while the post request fails).  I don't see anything in your controller code to suggest you are rendering a view inside a Post request, but I can't think of a better explanation.  For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething() 
{
    ...
    return View(Index);
}
```

And inside your `Index.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Action("GetWorkList")
```

That's an example where I could see it failing in the same manner.  Because the view was rendered in the context of a post request, the partial view also gets invoked as a post request instead of a get.